# Laravel, Ajax, Flash Messaging

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Okay, I'm stumped on this. What I am trying to do is save a flash message to the session, then display it on the page that I redirect to after an Ajax request.

I have it working on one page, but not the other.

My Ajax request is sent to my AuthController. In the method subscribe() I am calling a flash function:

```
flash("You now have full access!");
```

Then, in my $.post() call, I do this:

```
window.location.replace(redirect);
```

And like I said, this works on one page, but not another. I have two versions of the page, one that asks for credit card info, and one that just creates a user. The one that just creates a user passes the message fine when I redirect. But the page that has two Ajax calls, one to create the user, and the other to process their payment, doesn't pass the message.

I tried disabling the redirect and then manually going to another page to see if the flash message is passed after the user was created and the payment was processed, but the message is not there (I have a section in my master blade template that is already set up to display my flash messages).

I was having this same problem on the registration page without credit card info and the problem was that I was redirecting to a page that was blocked with a middleware and so my flash message was being killed. But this is not the case with the registration page with credit card info. It is just trying to redirect to the /home page and the user is logged in, so it should work... But it's not.

Here is the relevant code:

In the JS:

```
Stripe.card.createToken(ccData, function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {

    if (response.error) {
        console.log(response.error.param);
        switch (response.error.param) {
            case 'number':
                console.log('problem with card number');
                if ($('.bg-danger.card').length) {
                    $('.bg-danger.card').remove();
                }
                $form.find('[name=cardNumber]').parents('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                $form.find('[name=cardNumber]').parent('div').append('<div class="bg-danger card"><p>' + response.error.message + '</p></div>');
                break;
            case 'exp_year':
            case 'exp_month':
                if ($('.bg-danger.year').length) {
                    $('.bg-danger.year').remove();
                }
                $form.find('[name=cardExpiry]').parents('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                $form.find('[name=cardExpiry]').parent('div').append('<div class="bg-danger year"><p>' + response.error.message + '</p></div>');
                break;
            case 'cvc':
                if ($('.bg-danger.cvc').length) {
                    $('.bg-danger.cvc').remove();
                }
                $form.find('[name=cardCVC]').parents('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                $form.find('[name=cardCVC]').parent('div').append('<div class="bg-danger cvc"><p>' + response.error.message + '</p></div>');
                break;
            default:
                console.log('There was a problem');
        }
        /* Visual feedback */
        $form.find('[type=submit]').html('Please Try Again').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#userBillingMessage').html('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">' + response.error.message + '</div>');
        $('#userBillingMessage').show();
    } else {
        /* Visual feedback */
        console.log('should not be here');
        $form.find('[type=submit]').html('Processing').prop('disabled', true);
        /* Hide Stripe errors on the form */
        $('.payment-errors').closest('.input').hide();
        $('.payment-errors').text("");
        // response contains id and card, which contains additional card details
        console.log(response.id);
        console.log(response.card);
        var formToken = $form.find('[name=_token]').val();
        var token = response.id;
        var email = $form.find('[name=email]').val();

        console.log(email);
        // AJAX - you would send 'token' to your server here.
        console.log(token);
        $.post('/subscribe', {
            _token: formToken,
            email: email,
            token: token
        }, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        })
            // Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
            .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $('#userBilling .bg-danger').remove();
                if (data.error) {
                    //handle errors
                    $('.card-input').find('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                    $('#userBillingMessage').html('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">' + data.error.message + '</div>');
                    $('#userBillingMessage').show();
                    $form.find('[type=submit]').html('Please try again').prop('disabled', false);
                } else {
                    $('fieldset#userBilling').prop('disabled', true);
                    $('#userBillingMessage').html('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">You\'re Payment has been processed.</div>');
                    $('#userBillingMessage').show();
                    $form.find('[type=submit]').html('Success! Redirecting...').prop('disabled', true);
                    // check if intended exists
                    var redirect = '/home';
                    if($('#intended').length) {
                        redirect = $('#intended').text();
                    }
                    console.log(redirect);
                    // redirect
                    window.location.replace(redirect);
                }

            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log(jqXHR);
                $form.find('[type=submit]').html('Subscription failed').removeClass('success').addClass('error').prop('disabled', true);
                $('.payment-errors').text("Your subscription could not be processed at this time. Please refresh the page and try again.");
                $('.payment-errors').closest('.input').show();
            });
    }
});
}
```

In the AuthController:

```
public function subscribe(Request $request)
{

    $token = $request->input('token');
    $email = $request->input('email');

    $user = User::whereEmail($email)->first();
    if ($user == null) {
        return 'something went wrong...';
    } else {
        if ($user->subscribed()) {
            if ($user->onGracePeriod()) {
                $user->subscription('monthly')->resume($token);
            } else {
                return 'You are already subscribed to this site!';
            }
        } else {
            try {
                $user->subscription('monthly')->create($token, ['email' => $email]);
            } catch (\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
                return $e->getJsonBody();
            } catch (\Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest $e) {
                return $e->getJsonBody();
            } catch (\Stripe\Error\Authentication $e) {
                return $e->getJsonBody();
            } catch (\Stripe\Error\ApiConnection $e) {
                return $e->getJsonBody();
            } catch (\Stripe\Error\Base $e) {
                return $e->getJsonBody();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                return $e->getJsonBody();
            }
            // I flash the message here
            flash("You now have full access! Happy writing!");
        }
    }
}
```

The code is almost identical to the one that is working where I just make the call to AuthConroller postRegister method that looks like this:

```
 public function postRegister(Request $request, AppMailer $mailer)
{
    // Validate the request.
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }
    // This flash works!
    flash("Welcome to Story Shuttle! Before continuing, please confirm your email address by clicking the link in the email we sent you. Otherwise, you will not be able to log in again!");

    $user = $this->create($request->all());

    // Email confirmation link.
    $mailer->sendEmailConfirmationTo($user);

    Auth::login($user);

}
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Please let me know if you need any additional information. I'm going to work on some other features for now.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: my understanding and per Laravel doc, to flash data, you use   `Session::('key','value')` but you are using flash('string'). How come? and  how  does it work  in one instance but not the other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Laravel's Session::flash behaving inconsistently?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34686930/why-is-laravels-sessionflash-behaving-inconsistently)

Comment: @mdamia Check [laravel-flash](https://github.com/laracasts/flash) out!