# Why is Laravel's Session::flash behaving inconsistently?

Tags: php, laravel, session

While working on a Laravel 4.2 app, I have recently noticed that calls to `Session::flash` (and similarly `Input::flash`) sometimes behave inconsistently.

One particular example: I want to flash some data from the `edit` function so that I can access it in the corresponding `update` function. The `edit` view contains a fairly simple form, including one field that is loaded via an AJAX call after the user selects an option from a drop-down. Here is my [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

In `MyController.php`:

```
<?php

class MyController {
  public function edit($id) {
    Session::flash('somevar', "myvalue");

    return View::make('edit');
  }

  public function update($id) {
    var_dump(Session::all()); die();

    if (Session::has('somevar')) {
      // do stuff
    }

    return Redirect::to('/');
  }
}

?>
```

In `AjaxController.php`:

```
<?php

class AjaxController {
  public function getinfo() {
    return "here's that data you wanted";
  }
}

?>
```

In `edit.blade.php`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('form select[name=foo]').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/ajax/getinfo'
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
      }
    });
  });
</script>

<a href="/update/1">Update</a>
```

Sometimes the session dump in `update()` will show the flash data, but sometimes it is missing.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the extra AJAX call to populate one of the fields. Since this counts as a request, the flash data is active for that request, but not the next one.

To fix this issue, I added `Session::reflash()` to the first line of the function triggered by the AJAX call, like so:

```
<?php

class AjaxController {
  public function getinfo() {
    Session::reflash();

    return "here's that data you wanted";
  }
}

?>
```